# How to override default error messages in a django.forms subclass? - django 4.2.3

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I am in a spanish language country, so I need to show messages in spanish, can't use defaults error messages.

I am making tests, so I create a django.forms subclass with 1 char field, set it to required, set a min and max length. Used the error_messages parameter to set errors in spanish but still showing default messages. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Data is saved correctly the only problem is the error messages.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
class CreateNewList(forms.Form):
    nombre = forms.CharField(label="Nombre", max_length=200, min_length=3, required=True, error_messages = {
        'required': "El campo nombre es requerido", 
        'min_length': "El campo nombre debe ser minimo de 3 caracteres",
        'max_length': "El campo nombre debe ser menor a 200 caracteres"
        })
```

views.py

```
def crear(response):
    form = CreateNewList(response.POST or None)
    if response.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            n = form.cleaned_data["nombre"]
            t = ToDoList(nombre=n)
            t.save()

    return render(response,"main/crear.html", {"form": form})
```

With and empty input (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIIsm.png)

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change django localization in `settings.py`.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
```

Or for:

`es-AR` - Spanish - Argentina

`es-CO` - Spanish - Colombia

`es-MX` - Spanish - Mexico

`es-NI` - Spanish - Nicaragua

`es-PR` - Spanish - Puerto Rico

`es-VE` - Spanish - Venezuela

https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/conf/locale